# How to user iPhone X's prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden with Cordova

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, iphone-x

I'm creating an iPhone app with Cordova and having a problem with the home bar appearing above what it should.

The solution to this seems to be the prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden function as explained article[iphone-x-dealing-with-home-indicator](https://medium.com/the-traveled-ios-developers-guide/iphone-x-dealing-with-home-indicator-2e8e47f5647f).

However I'm not sure how this could be accessed or where it should be put in for the Cordova app.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use this [plugin](https://github.com/chipbell4/cordova-plugin-hide-home-indicator). Assigning true or false as return-value within prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden depends on whether you want to show the home-buton or not (in this [file](https://github.com/chipbell4/cordova-plugin-hide-home-indicator/blob/master/src/ios/HideHomeIndicatorPlugin.m)). Of course you have to set this return-value after your project has been built. Hope this help.